# Where does the destructor hide in this code?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics, move-constructor

I'm having trouble understanding why the `Foo` move constructor tries to invoke `~ptr` in the following example:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename Policy>
class ptr {
    T * m_t;
public:
    ptr() noexcept : m_t(0) {}
    explicit ptr(T *t) noexcept : m_t(t) {}
    ptr(const ptr &other) noexcept : m_t(Policy::clone(other.m_t)) {}
    ptr(ptr &&other) noexcept : m_t(other.m_t) { other.m_t = 0; }
    ~ptr() noexcept { Policy::delete_(m_t); }
    ptr &operator=(const ptr &other) noexcept
    { ptr copy(other); swap(copy); return *this; }
    ptr &operator=(ptr &&other) noexcept
    { std::swap(m_t,other.m_t); return *this; }

    void swap(ptr &other) noexcept { std::swap(m_t, other.m_t); }

    const T * get() const noexcept { return m_t; }
    T * get() noexcept { return m_t; }
};

class FooPolicy;
class FooPrivate;
class Foo {
    // some form of pImpl:
    typedef ptr<FooPrivate,FooPolicy> DataPtr;
    DataPtr d;
public:
    // copy semantics: out-of-line
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo &other);
    Foo &operator=(const Foo &other);
    ~Foo();

    // move semantics: inlined
    Foo(Foo &&other) noexcept
      : d(std::move(other.d)) {} // l.35 ERR: using FooDeleter in ~ptr required from here
    Foo &operator=(Foo &&other) noexcept
    { d.swap(other.d); return *this; }
};
```

GCC 4.7:

```
foo.h: In instantiation of ‘ptr<T, Policy>::~ptr() [with T = FooPrivate; Policy = FooPolicy]’:
foo.h:34:44:   required from here
foo.h:11:14: error: incomplete type ‘FooPolicy’ used in nested name specifier
```

Clang 3.1-pre:

```
foo.h:11:14: error: incomplete type 'FooPolicy' named in nested name specifier
    ~ptr() { Policy::delete_(m_t); }
             ^~~~~~~~
foo.h:34:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'ptr<FooPrivate, FooPolicy>::~ptr' requested here
    Foo(Foo &&other) : d(std::move(other.d)) {}
    ^
foo.h:23:7: note: forward declaration of 'FooPolicy'
class FooPolicy;
      ^
foo.h:11:20: error: incomplete definition of type 'FooPolicy'
    ~ptr() { Policy::delete_(m_t); }
             ~~~~~~^~
2 errors generated.
```

What's going on? I'm writing move constructors to avoid running copy ctors and dtors. Note that this is a header file that tries to hide its implementation (pimpl idiom), so making `FooDeleter` a full type isn't an option.

**EDIT**: After Bo's answer, I added `noexcept` everywhere I could (edited in above). But the errors are still the same.

Comment: stared at that code for a second and got a instant mini headache, thanks for the question, i had a similar issue recently thankfully had not to pursue

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but as the compiler messages point out, `Deleter(m_t);` doesn't mean what you think it means. It defines an unused redundantly parenthesised variable `m_t` of type `Deleter`.

Comment: "I'm writing move constructors to avoid running copy ctors and dtors." That's not a good reason to write a move constructor. The reasons to write move constructors are either because it's a low-level container type that needs move semantics, or you're using Visual Studio which doesn't implicitly generate move constructors for you. Otherwise, let the compiler do its job.

Comment: @hvd: ok, that was an oversimplification. I've used code closer to the original now (which is Qt's QScoped/ExplicitlySharedDataPointer, in case someone wants to have a deeper look: I get this error e.g. when `Foo` `->` `QPainterPath`).

Comment: @Nicol: According to N3092 [class.copy]/10, a user-defined
copy constructor prevents a compiler-synthesized move
constructor. But even with `Foo(Foo &&) = default`, I get the same error.

Comment: At the time of this writing, your example is broken.  The number of template arguments of `ptr` differ between `ptr` (2) and `Foo` (3)!  The templated call for deallocation can't be called `delete` since that's a keyword.  After fixing those, you probably should use a unifying assignment `ptr &operator =(ptr other) { this->swap(other); return *this; }` since it's easy for `ptr` to implement, with a slight de-optimization during move-assignments (due to the 2 calls to move-construction).

Comment: Reduced test case: https://cppinsights.io/s/81103404

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create a new `Foo` object that contains  a `ptr<something>` member. In case the `Foo` constructor fails, the compiler has to call the destructors for any completely constructed members of the partially constructed `Foo`.

But it cannot instantiate `~ptr<incomplete_type>()`, so that fails.

You have a similar case with a private destructor. That also stops you from creating objects of that type (unless done from a friend or a member function).

Comment: +1, and the solution in this case might be as simple as moving all constructor and destructor definitions to the implementation file where all types are complete.

Comment: +1; In other words, you cannot define any of `Foo`'s methods inline because you're hiding **all** of the details at the header level.  Assuming the changes from my [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417477/where-does-the-destructor-hide-in-this-code#comment12270235_9417477), you can use `Foo() :d(new FooPrivate) {} Foo(Foo const &) = default; Foo(Foo &&) = default; ~Foo() = default; Foo &operator=(Foo) = default;` as implementations, as `ptr` properly handles everything.

Comment: @Bo: Your answer sounded logical until I tried plastering all of `ptr`, as well as the `Foo` move ctor and assignment operator with `noexcept`. AFAIU, that was the original reason for `noexcept`: to allow move ctors to throw. I know mine can't, so why does GCC still invoke the dtor? I told it nothing there could fail, didn't I?

Comment: @Marc - I don't know if having `noexcept` everywhere helps, or if the compiler only sees that *after* trying to instantiate the destructor (which fails).